# Unable to sign in to Microsoft Account in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, azure, microsoft-account

This morning Cloud Explorer asked me to re-authenticate (as it seems to every few days!), but I can't enter my credentials. The link to re-authenticate now does nothing and when I click 'Manage accounts' and then 'Reenter your credentials', I get:

> The Type Initializer for
>   'Microsoft.IdentityService.Clients.ActiveDirectory.Authenticator'
>   threw and exception

Which means I can't continue the work I was doing (debugging my cloud service!).

Here's what I'm getting:

[image]

Has anyone seen this before or have any idea how to fix it? I've tried rebooting and restarting VS2017 and no joy...

Comment: Could you please share a call stack with us? for this you can:
1. Start an instance of Visual Studio,
2. In this instance set the exception settings to throw when the managed exceptions are thrown (Debug | Window | Exception Settings and check the checkbox named "Common Language Runtime Exception".
3. Start another instance of VS, and attach it from the first instance (Debug | Attach to Process ...)
When it fails, copy the call stack.

Comment: @Jean-MarcPrieur I followed your steps, but with the debugger attached, neither the 'reenderyour credentials' link nor the 'Manage Accounts' link respond to clicking, so can't get it to fail. If I detatch the debugger, the 'Sign in to visual studio' window (shown in my post) pops up on first click!

Comment: wouldn't your AAD admin have added conditional access policies ?